# Writing a dummy Network Shared Printer

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I want to write a dummy printer driver which appears as a shared printer on a LAN and can accept print jobs; so when its installed on a computer other computers in the LAN can browse and add it as a usual shared network printer and send print jobs to it. I want to do this in c#, are there any better suggestions?

Can anyone tell me any information regarding this, tips, tools, reading material etc. anything!

Comment: there's no such thing as "C#.Net". It's just "C#".

Comment: Thank you very much for educating me on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a printer that will accept jobs and not do anything with the data, you don't need to write your own printer driver.  Just create a local printer, and when it asks you for the port create a new local port and give it the name NUL.  From the [Windows XP Professional Product Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/print_c_portsw.mspx?mfr=true):

> If the printer is physically attached
>   to the print server, select the
>   appropriate local port. LPT1 through
>   LPT3 represent parallel ports; COM1
>   through COM4 represent serial ports
>   When a client prints to a printer port
>   denoted as FILE, the client is
>   prompted for the file name. If you
>   decide to add a new local port you can
>   enter one of the following:
>
> - A file name, such as C:\Dir\Filename. All jobs sent to this
>     port are written to the named file,
>     and each new job overwrites the last
>     one.
> - The share name of a printer, such as \Server\Printer (URLs are not
>     accepted). Jobs sent to this port are
>     transferred over the network to the
>     named share by the network redirector.
> - **NUL. This specifies the null port, which you can use to test whether
>     network clients can send jobs. Jobs
>     sent to NUL are deleted without
>     wasting paper or delaying real print
>     jobs.**
> - IR. Use this port to connect to infrared-enabled printers meeting
>     Infrared Data Association (IrDA)
>     specifications. If your hardware does
>     not support IR, it will not be listed
>     on the Ports tab.

Comment: thank you very much I appreciate your answer very much. That fulfilled many of my questions.

And yes I don't want to print the print jobs, just need to accept the print jobs and direct them to a desired real printer according to a print job routing table. Imagine 3 PCs. one is sending a print job to a dummy printer job acceptor software on another PC, and that pc then transfers it to a PC with a real printer. Thanks for your response, can u suggest me any reading materials or even topics, coz I have no idea, only the passion to do it is all I have. Also any suggestion is welcome! Thanks